# la función del controller no se ejecuta

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola quiero hacer un logout, pero no entra a la función logout del controller, y no me arroja ningún error por pantalla al presionar mi botón de cerrar sesión (el cual llama a logout del controller), si no que me recarga la misma página que sería el dashboard.

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TicketRedQ</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TicketRedQ</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

                <!-- Corte un pedazo, está en el archivo CtrlX -->


                @if (auth()->check())
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="/">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href=" {{ route('message.create') }}">Solicitudes</a></li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ auth()->user()->nombre_depto }}<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <form class="navbar-form pull-right" method="POST" action="{{ route('depto.logout') }}">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">
                                        Cerrar sesión
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                @endif

            <!--Hasta aquí corté -->
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        @if(session()->has('flash'))
            <div class="alert alert-info">{{ session('flash') }}</div>
        @endif
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Routes de depto

```
Route::prefix('depto')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/login','Auth\LoginDeptosController@showLoginForm')->name('depto.login');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\LoginDeptosController@login')->name('depto.login.submit');
    Route::post('/logout','Auth\LoginDeptosController@logout')->name('depto.logout');
    Route::get('/', 'DeptoController@index')->name('depto.dashboard');
 });
```

LoginDeptoController

```
<?php    
class LoginDeptosController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:depto');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.deptologin');
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = $this->validate(request(), [
            $this->nombre_depto() => 'required|string|min:4',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6'
        ]);


       if(Auth::guard('depto')->attempt($credentials))
       {
        return redirect()->intended(route('depto.dashboard')); 
       }
        return back()
                ->withErrors([$this->nombre_depto() => 'Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros'])
                ->withInput(request([$this->nombre_depto()]));
    }
    public function nombre_depto()
    {
        return 'nombre_depto';
    }

     public function logout()
    {
        //Auth::guard('depto')->logout();
        return 'holi';
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que no usasel sistema de logout por defecto de laravel

Comment: porque estoy haciendo multiauth, me loguea, pero al momento de hacer logout no entra a la función del controller

Comment: Has verificado que tu ruta este señalando correctamente o este bien establecida?, y si llamas a otra función, cambia algo?